# Can't create geometrical Point from float data using Geopandas / Shapely

Tags: point, geopandas, shapely

I keep getting errors trying to do a basic transformation of 2 coordinate columns to a Point object, in order to create a GeoPandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

x = np.random.normal(size=10).tolist()
y = np.random.normal(size=10).tolist()
dict0 = {
    'x':x,
    'y':y
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict0)

# the geopandas.points_from_xy doesnt seem to exist anymore
gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,gpd.points_from_xy(df.x,df.y))

#this raises the error of cannot convert to class
gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,geometry=Point(df.x,df.y))
```

So the geopandas way raises the error: 
`AttributeError: module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'points_from_xy'`
Perhaps it doesn't exist anymore? Either way, the alternative is to use the Point from Shapely.

The shapely way raises the following error:

```
raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to " "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

The x and y data clearly are float data. Any ideas how to surpass this error, and get a Point?

Comment: `gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.x,df.y))` works for me. `points_from_xy` does exist in the latest release. Which version do you use?

Comment: Hi Martin, I was running geopandas version 0.4.1 and updated it to 0.6.1. It did solve the has no attribute 'points_from_xy' issue, however it resulted in a new error. "TypeError: unhashable type: 'Point'" - I am looking into that error.